# seo custom domains

Tags: apache, dns

I'm trying to do the following:

I have website like apartments.com.

sometimes, I want to expand to different cities, so for SEO purposes, I might create a separate domain like bostonapartments.com or newyorkapartments.com for only boston and new york apartments.

bostonapartments.com and the main domain apartments.com are all hosted on 1 server. what I did was I used Virtual Host apache config to direct bostonapartments.com to a directory on that server, and then used an iframe to load content for bostonapartments.com from apartments.com. So all the content will be hosted on apartments.com, but bostonapartments.com will get the content from apartments.com.

how can I accomplish this effectively in a scalable way using php, apache, mysql?

btw, I do not own apartments.com, I'm just using that as an example.

Answer (score 0):

Why such a contrived solution? Just add `ServerAlias` directives for all of your domains straight in the `apartments.com` virtual host.

Answer (score 0):

if they are all identical it will do more bad than good due to duplicate content, but as @lanzz said, ServerAlias will do the same thing.

I would suggest separate
 virtual servers and optimize each site with keywords, writing, etc etc.